# Play audio file on hover (and stop playing on mouseout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

What is the best solution to play an audio file on mouse over via JavaScript? And stop it when the mouse leaves the link. jQuery is available.

```
<a href="/test.mp3" class="play">play</a>
```

Comment: As a member of humanity, I ask you to at least make this a `click` event.

Comment: As a fan of clear (HT) Markup Language I want to keep this link to a audio file. Adding just a little JS fancy...

Comment: I think you missed my point, as a majority, users prefer not to have a sound startup when simply moving their mouse across the page, it *should* be a click, not a hover.  Why do you think flash based ads with high volume are going away and ad/flash blockers usage is skyrocketing? A lot of the same reasoning applies here...just something you should consider.

Comment: @Nick: Its for an application which handles a lot of audio files and clicking is slower than hovering. It is for a backend administration tool and it is necessary to figure out very fast what file it is...

Answer (score 3):

```
<audio id="mysound" src="mysound.wav"></audio>
<button onmouseover="document.getElementById('mysound').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('mysound').pause()">Hover me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/
Provides HTML5 + legacy support

Comment: SoundManager is a little heavy. No other suggestions?

Comment: I have seen this used well in a different game development events +1, it works -- I have no idea about the other alternatives. I am also interested if there is some minimalistic solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function(){
                $("a.play").each(function() {
                  $(this).mouseover(function(){ 
                       var mp3file = $(this).attr('href');
                       // asign this mp3file to the player and play it
                  }).mouseout(function() { 
                       // tell the mp3 player to stop
                  });
                });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

you can use the player that unomi suggested. works great

Comment: 2 Things here, there's a `.hover()` function you should check out, and there's never any need for `.each()` when binding, just call `$("a.play").click()` for example, it'll bind each of the matches for that selector :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I forgot about hover!

Comment: @NickCraver is it possible to get your alternative solution as an answer? I don't like that the answerer has not improved his answer after your comment. It would make this writing higher quality.