# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null at playAudio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to have audio play when the mouse hovers over a link. I. keep getting this error when i hover or click and I am unsure how to fix it.

the full error says this:
'Cannot read property 'play' of null
    at playAudio (audio.js:8)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onmouseenter (VM974 audio.html:16)'

Here is my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='audio.js'></script>
  <body>
<nav>
  <a href="#" onmouseenter="playAudio()">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
<audio id="audioID">
  <source src="h.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="b.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and here is my javascript (audio.js):

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audioID");

function playAudio() {
    audio1.play();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to ask a specific question. Is the problem you don't unterstand the error message? Also be aware that debugging someone else's code requires all details so that some else can reproduce your problem. For example, what's in ``audio.js``? Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can be onmouseover or oncick ?

Comment: for example like this [codepen.io/pen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExVOdwK?editors=1100)

Comment: @MaximLensky neither are working

Comment: @Ivo thank you. I kinda understand that the error message is saying that the play function is not working but have not been able to fix it. I posted what is in audio.js as my javascript code.

Comment: put your link to the audio -

Comment: they are files on my computer

Comment: or just wait 10-15 seconds, the music will start when hovering

Comment: Two things I'd do. First, move your JS from ``audio.js`` to your HTML page. Second, make sure that ``var audio1 = document.getElementById("audioID");`` comes **after** your `<audio id="audioID">` element.

Comment: I checked in Firefox and so did Google Chrome - we have to wait 10 seconds

Comment: @Ivo putting the JS in the HTML allows me to use onclick, but when I hover over it says the use has not interacted with the document. `.getElementById` is after  `<audio id="audioID">`

Comment: I get the feeling that doing it in this way is leading nowhere. Have you checked SO for already existing solutions to solve your problem? Searching SO turns up quite a few Q/A dealing with this topic already. Is it a possible duplicate of [Play audio file on hover (and stop playing on mouseout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013883/play-audio-file-on-hover-and-stop-playing-on-mouseout/3014122#3014122). Also instead of doing ping/pong in the comments, put your approach into JSFiddle example and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!

```
//Replace and Work

function playAudio() {
var audio1 = document.getElementById("audioID");
    audio1.play();
}
```